# How to read xep file data in java

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

is there any way to get total number of page count before pdf render completely and input we are giving xml file and xslt is style sheet for page layout,and we are using RenderX for pdf conversion from xslt it is converted to xsl-fo file and from xsl-fo it is converting to xep file and from xep it is converting to ps/pdf file.
and one more question how to read data from xep file by using java in xep it is containing page numbers and id etc.

Comment: What kind of  xep-file? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're not ready to ask a question here.  Read [**Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)  Then read [ask].  Then write some code.  Then come back with a [mcve] and a specific question regarding where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The XEP format is an xml document. You can look in the RenderX documentation for the structure and meaning of all the tags. Since it is XML, one could use many methods to extract and even change it.

Pages are represented by the xep:page element. You can examine this element in the XEP format and get page number and other information.