# How to fetch page_number or id from XEP file by using Java

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have receiving a file from server which is XEP extension file, so here is my thing how to fetch data from this file. I used the basic java file read program but unable to get those values from XEP file. In XEP file only node tag are present and data also with in node tag.

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266729/how-to-read-xep-file-data-in-java

Comment: Didn't get much information from which you referred  @michael.hor257k .

Comment: I referred manly to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266729/how-to-read-xep-file-data-in-java#comment118898639_67266729

Comment: You received a generous answer from one of the foremost authorities on XEP to a question that was too vague and too broad to be answerable in detail.  Answers are not going to get any better by just repeating same question without further effort on your part.  Re-read and address the points of my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266729/how-to-read-xep-file-data-in-java#comment118898639_67266729) to make best use of the resources here.  Thanks.